# Добавить к картинке href с помощью javascript (без jQuery)

Tags: javascript

На странице выведена картинка: `<span id=counter><img id=piccounter src='picurl' /></span>`

Нужно добавить к картинке ссылку `<a href='http://url.ru'><img id=piccounter src='picurl' /></a>`

Простой javascript. Без jQuery.

(Это счетчик ЛИ. Хочу добавлять ссылку на него в отдельном js.)

Comment: что значит "Добавить к картинке ссылку"?

Comment: причём тут какой-то счётчик ЛИ?)

Comment: исправил сообщение

Answer (score 0):

```js
// ищем элементы
span = document.querySelector('#counter')
img = span.querySelector('#piccounter')
// создаем ссылку
a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = "http://url.ru"
// ставим все на место
a.appendChild(img)
span.appendChild(a)
```

```html
На странице выведена картинка: <span id="counter"><img id="piccounter" src='picurl' /></span>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! 
А чем querySelector('#li') лучше getElementById(''li)?

Comment: в такой ситуации, видимо, ничем

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let span = document.querySelector('#counter')
let img = span.innerHTML
span.innerHTML =`<a href='http://url.ru'>${img}</a>`
```

```html
<span id="counter"><img id="piccounter" src='picurl' /></span>
```